# How to add a separate product to my Stripe payment system? Python3 Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, web, stripe-payments, payment

So after a day or two, I’ve finally gotten Stripe to work on my computer locally and have also tested my code on a production server. It works fine when I'm only providing one product. However I am new to using Stripe and was wondering if anyone could tell me how I would add two products to my webapp in Flask.

Here is the code that works without the stripe_webhook.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, abort
import random
import subprocess
import stripe

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'TEST_PUBLIC_KEY'
app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'TEST_SECRET_KEY'

stripe.api_key = app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/initialpay')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html', 
    )

    
@app.route('/stripe_pay')
def stripe_pay():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': 'price_1LoHWRFnHWt4LiAiajHaqMdl',
            'quantity': 1, 
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('thanks', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('index', _external=True),
    )
    return {
        'checkout_session_id': session['id'], 
        'checkout_public_key': app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
    }

@app.route('/thanks')
def thanks():
    return render_template("thanks.html")
```

Now I have tried adding two checkout sessions to reflect the two products as well as two index pages. As you can see below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, abort
import random
import subprocess
import stripe

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] = 'TEST_PUBLIC_KEY'
app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'] = 'TEST_SECRET_KEY'

stripe.api_key = app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


@app.route('/initialpayFORFIRSTPRODUCT')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html', 
    )

@app.route('/initialpayFORSECONDPRODUCT')
def index():
    return render_template(
        'index.html', 
    )
@app.route('/stripe_payFIRST')
def stripe_payFIRST():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': 'price_OF_FIRST_PRODUCT',
            'quantity': 1, 
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('thanks', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('index', _external=True),
    )
    return {
        'checkout_session_id': session['id'], 
        'checkout_public_key': app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
    }


@app.route('/stripe_paySECOND')
def stripe_paySECOND():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price': 'price_OF_SECOND_PRODUCT',
            'quantity': 1, 
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('thanks', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('index', _external=True),
    )
    return {
        'checkout_session_id': session['id'], 
        'checkout_public_key': app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
    }

@app.route('/thanks')
def thanks():
    return render_template("thanks.html")
```

If anyone can help, please let me know. The problem I am having is that despite using a my second price ID for my second checkout session. Stripe still shows my first product(price ID) for the second checkout session. I don't know why, I have checked and each price ID is different, so I don't know why they are the same price and why they have the same name when in my Stripe account it clearly shows 2 different names and 2 different prices.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your goal to create two Checkout Sessions (one for each price), or to create a single Checkout Session with both prices?

Comment: @LauraT My goal is too create two separate checkout sessions(one for each price), thank you for letting me explain. However, when I attempt this, it seems that the checkout session still uses the same price/product despite both being two different products(price IDs).

Comment: I see you're using the same 'index.html' page for both '/initialpayFORFIRSTPRODUCT' and '/initialpayFORSECONDPRODUCT'. How are you calling the 'stripe_paySECOND' function?

Just to take a step back here, it may make more sense to define a single function to create a Checkout Session instead of duplicating code. You can use a variable for 'line_items.price', and base the value of that variable on any client-side actions taken by your customer.